# How to ping website using PHP?

Tags: php, ping

I want to ping website using php.

I want to get the ping result in table including this information

```
Packet.
IP Address.
ms.
TTL
And if the signal is lost or not.
```

I want to set limit of packet to 5.

Comment: To find this on the internet, put "PHP ping" in your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
<?php

function pingAddress($ip) {
    $pingresult = exec("ping  -n 3 $ip", $outcome, $status);
    if (0 == $status) {
        $status = "alive => ( ".print_r($outcome)." )";
    } else {
        $status = "dead";
    }
    echo "The IP address, $ip, is  ".$status;
}

pingAddress("www.google.com");

 ?>
```

**Remember to enable `exec()` function through `php.ini` !!!**